# How to Disable Ping Response (ICMP echo) in Linux all the time?

Tags: ping, icmp

I want to disable ping response all the time on my Ubuntu operating system, the following commands work but only until the system reboots:

Ping off:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Ping on:

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

How would I be able to leave echo off even after having rebooted my laptop?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> How would I be able to leave echo off even when I am rebooting my laptop?

You can use one of the following three ways (as root):

### Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Add the following line to your `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

Then:

```
sysctl -p
```

### Using iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

### With cron

Run `crontab -e` as root, then add the following line:

```
@reboot echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Start and enable the service:

```
systemctl start cron.service
systemctl enable cron.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using UFW and trying to apply the `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all` setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, you may find that this does not have any effect after a reboot. In that case, have a look for the same setting in `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf` and change it there.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian-based Linux distributions that ship with UFW application firewall, you can block ICMP messages by adding the following rule to `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file:

```
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```